# Serialize object by condition

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have following JSON

```
{"id":"154298_child","design":{"id":154298,"alias":"SOME NAME","published_at":"2013-02-04T00:00:00+0400","author":[]} }
```

and this one

```
{"id":"292171_manshort","design":{"id":292171,"alias":"some name2","published_at":"2014-04-08T00:00:00+0400","author":{"nickname":"Malkia"}}}
```

Than I deserialing them to object

```
public class Data
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Design design { get; set; }
}
public class Design
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public DateTime published_at { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Author>))]
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
}
```

with converter

```
class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The question is:
How serialize object by condition
**if(Author.Count>1)=>then second example of json (to object)**
**if(Author.Count==0)=>then first example of json (to array)**

Comment: Those would be completely different entities in C#. Instead I would recommend setting author to null during serialization, or allowing it to be an array of one item in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    List<Author> list = value as List<Author>;
    int count = list?.Count ?? 0;

    JToken t;

    // count > 1 ?
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        t = JToken.FromObject(list[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        t = JToken.FromObject(new List<Author>());
    }

    t.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Don't forget to set `CanWrite` to true

```
public override bool CanWrite
{
    get { return true; }
}
```